# Merging df 10 x 10 km raster grid based on coordinates in R

Tags: r, dplyr, mapping, raster

1. I am looking to create a df that contains 10x10 km grid over a specified area (coordinate bounds) in R.
2. Then, I am looking to assign a grid square from the new df to an existing df with latitude and longitude, year, presence/absence and other data
   Sample of current df:

| LONGITUDE | LATITUDE | Year | Presence | Set |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 67.71150 | 67.71150 | 2017 | Y | 1 |
| 67.72150 | 67.72150 | 2017 | N | 2 |

So, the new df would ideally look like this:

| LONGITUDE | LATITUDE | Year | Presence | Set | Grid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 67.71150 | 67.71150 | 2017 | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 67.72150 | 67.72150 | 2017 | N | 2 | 1 |

Comment: When asking an R question, please include a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example*. That is include R code that creates example data, and show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(res=1/12, xmin=0, xmax=90, ymin=0, ymax=90) 
df$cell <- cellFromXY(r, df[, ("LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE")])
```

Note that you talk about 10 km (planar) resolution, but your coordinates are angular (long/lat). You cannot directly match different coordinate reference systems. The raster I created is also lon/lat, and it has a 5-minute resolution which is approximately 5 km (except at high latitudes). You can also create a planar raster, and tranform your coordinates to the same crs.